# Rails 3.2.x remote=>true still reloads a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've been searching all over and can't figure out why this isn't working.

I'm trying to test a very basic ajax action. Here are my code:

Controller:

```
def commit
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :action => "index" } # see note 1
        format.js { render :layout => false } # see note 2
        format.js { render :nothing => true } 
    end
end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to "commit", :action => "commit", :remote => true %>
<%= form_tag( :action => "commit", :remote => true, :method => :post) do %>
     <%= submit_tag "commit" %>
<% end %>

<div id='message'></div>
```

commit.js.erb

```
console.log('committed');
$('#message').html("committed");
```

The problem is I'd get to the commit method, but the page would reload, which defeats the point of remote=>true
Also the commit.js never seemed to get called.

Note 1: If I exclude this line, I get the blank page to /commit. Including it makes the page just reload
Note 2: I've tried both of these approaches suggested by other SO posts
Note 3: I've tried both using link_to and form_tag

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why did you put there 2 lines?

```
    format.js { render :layout => false } # see note 2
    format.js { render :nothing => true }
```

Remove the second one!

Replace:

```
<%= link_to "commit", :action => "commit", :remote => true %>
```

with:

```
<%= link_to "commit", commit_path, :remote => true %>
```

---

The same with the form:

Make your:

```
<%= form_tag( :action => "commit", :remote => true, :method => :post) do %>
```

as:

```
<%= form_tag(commit_path, :remote => true) do %>
```

Note: `POST` is the default behavior, you can omit it from `form_tag`.

Comment: I see! Turns out either format.js argument works, but I just need to pass in the path instead of :action! Thanks!

Comment: See it this way: `:action` defines path, `:remote` defines way of it's handling. It's weird to put them together. What if you want `:remote` to be passed in `params`? It would be a mess!